# How to use Gradle in a Processing project?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, processing, google-sheets-api

I'm about to begin a project that involves making a graphical UI with processing and drawing data from a google spreadsheet.

I've used processing before, but I'm not sure how to use gradle, especially not with the processing IDE, or otherwise access the google sheets api... the guide on [google](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) and gradle's sites don't seem applicable to my situation, so I'm sorta confused by them.

Comment: What exactly confuses you in the Google guide?

Comment: The Google guide you link to only shows how to create a Java project using Gradle and consume the Google Sheets API. Gradle is supported by most Java IDEs (usually Eclipse or IntelliJ) so you can import Gradle projects easily from them. Processing seems to have its own IDE, check if you can find support for Gradle in it.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any support for it. Do you think I should have a separate project for accessing the google sheets api, and have my processing project call it?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. Looks like you can create a Processing library which uses the Google Sheets API, then import it from your main Processing project.

Comment: Why do you need to use Gradle at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle is a build tool for Java (and other languages) projects, similar to Maven. IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ support it so you can import projects that use Gradle easily in either IDE.

But it seems that the Processing IDE does not have any support for Gradle, at least as far as I can see.

But I found that someone published a [Processing library template](https://github.com/endoh0509/processing-library-template-gradle) which seems to allow you to build a Processing library with Gradle which you can then use from the Processing IDE (you should be able to import it as a library, I think).

Give that a try, hope it works.